# In objective-c how to play multiple video url one after another with out inbetween buffering

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my project I have to play multiple video one after another from server and I have done the following code. My video is playing well but the problem is that while one video is finished I am playing the next video in the -(void)aMoviePlaybackComplete method a black screen is appearing for 1 or 2 seconds. I dont want that and also want to play the video without buffering. Is there any better way to do this? If possible please kindly share valuable code or related links.

Thanks in advance.

```
      -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
        {
                NSURL * myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrVideoLink objectAtIndex:0]];
                moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:myUrl];
                moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;

                [vwVideoview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
                moviePlayer.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, vwVideoview.frame.size.width, vwVideoview.frame.size.height);           
                moviePlayer.view.layer.zPosition = 1;
                [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

                [moviePlayer play];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                              object:moviePlayer];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(aMoviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                           object:moviePlayer];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                           object:moviePlayer];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(nowPlayingMovie:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification
                                                           object:moviePlayer];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                                           object:moviePlayer];
        }

     - (void)aMoviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification*)notification
       {
                        if (urlIndex+1<=arrVideoLink.count-1)
                        {
                            NSURL * myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrVideoLink objectAtIndex:urlIndex+1]];
                            moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:myUrl];
                            moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
                            [vwVideoview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
                            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, vwVideoview.frame.size.width, vwVideoview.frame.size.height);            
                            moviePlayer.view.layer.zPosition = 1;           
                            [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];    
                                 [moviePlayer play];

                                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                          selector:@selector(aMoviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                                              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                                            object:moviePlayer];
                                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification   object:moviePlayer];                
              urlIndex++;    
                             }

                        }else
                        {
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
                                [player.view removeFromSuperview];                
                            }
  }
```